# Máscara jquery.inputmask com valores em moeda Real

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando o plugin [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) para vários tipos de máscara nos imputs da minha aplicação e inclusive para **formatar moedas**.

Estou utilizando a seguinte regra customizada:

```js
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#money").inputmask('decimal', {
            'alias': 'decimal',
            'radixPoint': ','
            'groupSeparator': '.'
            'autoGroup': true,
            'digits': 2,
            'digitsOptional': false,
            'rightAlign': false
            'placeholder': '0'
    });
</script>
```

Com valores muito específicos funciona muito bem, por exemplo: `R$ 2.500,50`.
Já com valores arredondados, por exemplo: `R$ 2.000,00` (ao recuperar os dados do BD) a máscara está trocando o ponto pela vírgula e retornando um valor `R$ 2,00`.

Alguém conseguiu contornar esse problema para moedas em Real?

Comment: More specific details: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues/1418

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível utilizar o método callback `onBeforeMask()` para contornar o problema de conversão decimal pt-br.

```
$('.moedaReal').inputmask('decimal', {
      radixPoint:",",
      groupSeparator: ".",
      autoGroup: true,
      digits: 2,
      digitsOptional: false,
      placeholder: '0',
      rightAlign: false,
      onBeforeMask: function (value, opts) {
        return value;
      }
});
```

Um bug foi registrado para correção na biblioteca.